# Insert schemaLocation in the XML File using XSLT v2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having a problem inserting a schemaLocation in the XML File. I almost got the expected output but the other elements populates the schemaLocation. Here is my sample file:

**INPUT:**

```
<Sync releaseID="9.2">
<Document>
    <Group>
        <Header>
            <Field1>232</Field1>
            <Field2>dfd</Field2>
        </Header>
    </Group>
</Document>
```

And, I want to add the namespace and schemalocation in `<Document>` tag. Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::Document]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**GENERATED OUTPUT:**

```
<Sync releaseID="9.2">
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
    <Group xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
        <Header xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
            <Field1 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">232</Field1>
            <Field2 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">dfd</Field2>
        </Header>
    </Group>
</Document>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<Sync releaseID="9.2">
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
    <Group>
        <Header>
            <Field1>232</Field1>
            <Field2>dfd</Field2>
        </Header>
    </Group>
</Document>
```

How can I remove the schemaLocation in the other elements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **add** a template matching `Document` only and add the attribute there (and only there). Then change your existing template so that it matches only descendants of `Document`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[ancestor::Document]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Document">
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And there's one more subtlety which is that xsi:schemaLocation needs to be a pair of URIs: one for the namespace, and one for the actual location.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You're so great @michael.hor257k. By the way, can you tell me when I need to use the function <xsl:element name="Sample"> to the direct use of element name <Sample>? Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: @Charlotte Use the `xsl:element` instruction when the name or the namespace of the element must be determined at runtime. Otherwise it's better to use a literal result element.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to do this special processing for the `Document` element, not for every element that has `Document` as an ancestor, so just change the match pattern from `match="*[ancestor-or-self::Document]"` to `match="Document"`.

Comment: If you do that (and nothing else) it will keep the descendants of `Document` in no-namespace - which is **not** the expected output.

Comment: OK, I missed that.